# Will a 16mm bushing fit on a 17mm rear sway bar?

Tags: mazda, bushing, swaybar

Looking to replace my rear sway bar bushings. The only size I can find for my generation of Mazda is 16mm.
My bar is 17mm. Will this be OK ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that those are the right bushings, the difference between 16mm and 17mm is so slight that it's likely a coat of paint or a buildup of crud that's making the measurement difference between 16 and 17mm. Unless you have some sort of strange aftermarket setup those will almost certainly work for you.